# Get values from two activities in the same activity android

Tags: android

I have 3 `activities A B & C`, I have to go to `Activity B & C` from `Activity A`, I need a data from editText in `Activity A from B & C`. What I need when I go the `Activity B` this time If I click on submit it will get the values from `B` to `A`, & when I'll go to `Activity C` this time if I click on submit it will get the value from `C` to `A`.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Use startActivityForResult() instead of startActivity(). Also override the method onActivityResult() in Activity A.

Answer (score 0):

The question isn't really clear.

Anyway, if you need to open an activity and passing data to it you just need to add extras in the intent. More info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html)

If you need to start an activity and obtain a result from it use the startActivityForResult().
More info [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)